# Polymer - Styling paper-input element

Tags: css, polymer

I am working on a Polymer app. There's so much I like and then there's some magic that I don't fully understand yet. At this time, I'm trying to figure out how to style the `paper-input` element. I have one defined like this:

```
<div class="horizontal layout">
  <iron-icon icon="schedule" style="padding:18px 12px 0px 0px;"></iron-icon>
  <paper-input label="started at" readonly="true" value="[[ time ]]"></paper-input>
</div>
```

The above code generates a paper-input element. However, I have two challenges with it. First, when a user clicks the content of the text field, an underline appears. However, I marked it as readonly, so I did not think the field could receive focus. Second, I do not want an underline of any kind. Even when the field doesn't have focus. I never want to show an underline. Yet, when I inspect the DOM, I can't figure out how to set that.

Is there a way to remove the underline and focus? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underline as you say is part of the Material Design spec for `paper-input`. If you want to remove it, you will have to play with the following mixins:

```
`--paper-input-container-underline` | Mixin applied to the underline | `{}`
`--paper-input-container-underline-focus` | Mixin applied to the underline when the input is focused | `{}`
`--paper-input-container-underline-disabled` | Mixin applied to the underline when the input is disabled | `{}`
```